# How to fix the code for trigger that prevent the insert based on some conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger that I have problems with.
The triggers work is to stop the item from inserting.
Here there are 2 tables of student and subjects.
I have to check and prevent inserting when the student has not enrolled in that subject and if he has he will start it from the next semester so currently he is not enrolled there.
Please help me with this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_student 
BEFORE INSERT ON subject
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.student_no 
    AND :new.student_name  NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT student_no,student_name 
        FROM student
    ) 
    OR :new.student_enrollment_date < (
        select min(enrolment_date) 
        from student 
        where 
            student.student_name = :new.student_name 
            and student.student_no = :new.guest_no 
        group by student.student_name , student.student_no
    )
    AND :new.student_name = (
        select distinct student_name 
        from student
    )
    AND :new.student_no = (
        select distinct student_no 
        from student
    )
    THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Person must have lived there');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

I have to check and prevent inserting when the student has not enrolled in that subject and if he has he will start it from the next semester so currently he is not enrolled there.

Please help me with this.

Comment: what will be your desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a logical prescedence issues in your conditions, since it contains `AND`s and `OR`s without any parentheses. Also, you are checking scalar values against subqueries that return more than one row or more than one column, this will generate runtime errors.

But overall, I think that your code can be simplified by using a unique `NOT EXISTS` condition with a subquery that checks if all functional conditions are satisfied at once. This should be pretty close to what you want:

```
create or replace trigger check_student 
before insert on subject
for each row
begin
    if not exists (
        select 1
        from student
        where 
            name = :new.student_name 
            and student_no = :new.student_no
            and enrolment_date <= :new.student_enrollment_date 
    ) then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Person must have livd there');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Note: it is unclear what is the purpose of colum `:new.guest_no`, so I left it apart from the time being (I assumed that you meant `:new.student_no` instead).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite unclear so I am just using the same conditions as used by you in your question to let you know how to proceed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_STUDENT BEFORE
    INSERT ON SUBJECT
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    LV_STU_COUNT             NUMBER := 0; --declared the variables
    LV_STU_ENROLLED_FUTURE   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(1)
    INTO LV_STU_COUNT -- assigning value to the variable
    FROM
        STUDENT
    WHERE
        STUDENT_NO = :NEW.STUDENT_NO
        AND STUDENT_NAME = :NEW.STUDENT_NAME;

    -- ADDED BEGIN EXCEPTION BLOCK HERE
    BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(1)
    INTO LV_STU_ENROLLED_FUTURE -- assigning value to the variable
    FROM
        STUDENT
    WHERE
        STUDENT.STUDENT_NAME = :NEW.STUDENT_NAME
        AND STUDENT.STUDENT_NO = :NEW.GUEST_NO
    GROUP BY
        STUDENT.STUDENT_NAME,
        STUDENT.STUDENT_NO
    HAVING
        MIN(ENROLMENT_DATE) > :NEW.STUDENT_ENROLLMENT_DATE;
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       LV_STU_ENROLLED_FUTURE  := 0;
    END;

    -- OTHER TWO CONDITIONS SAME LIKE ABOVE, IF NEEDED

    -- using variables to raise the error
    IF LV_STU_COUNT = 0 OR ( LV_STU_ENROLLED_FUTURE >= 1 /* AND OTHER CONDITIONS*/ ) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Person must have livd there');
    END IF;

END;
/
```

Cheers!!

Comment: INSERT INTO review VALUES (41,'An outstanding apartment in an amazing location, very friendly staff and the cleaning staff did a great job! Overall a perfect apartment for a weekend break',to_date('10-03-2019','dd-mm-yyyy'),4,1,5);

Comment: Error starting at line : 96 in command -
INSERT INTO review VALUES (41,'An outstanding apartment in an amazing location, very friendly staff and the cleaning staff did a great job! Overall a perfect apartment for a weekend break',to_date('10-03-2019','dd-mm-yyyy'),4,1,5)
Error report -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "PARO0004.CHECK_REVIEW", line 16
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'PARO0004.CHECK_REVIEW'

Comment: User the same trigger but getting this issue. This is for the correct input. The wrong input is being filtered so that is fine but this is not working for the correct insert.

Comment: I have updated the answer to handle this issue. Please check now. -- ADDED BEGIN EXCEPTION BLOCK in second query